# Converting my function to assembly from C

Tags: c, assembly

Hi I have a function in C that returns the max of a set of numbers in an array. I need to convert it into assembly and make it callable from C. nums is the array in which all the numbers are stored. len is the length of the array that was passed. The other variables that I made are local variables

```
.global max
.text
.equ word_size, 4
max: 
#prologue
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp

.equ nums, 2*word_size
.equ len, 3*word_size
.equ cur_max, 4*word_size
.equ index, 5*word_size
#eax is index

#short cur_max = nums[0]    
movl cur_max(%ebp), %eax
movl $0, %ebx
mov nums(%ebp), %edx 
leal (%edx, %ebx, word_size), %edx 
mov %edx, cur_max(%ebp)

#for(index = 1; index < len;index++)
mov index(%ebp), %eax
mov len(%ebp), %ebx
mov nums(%ebp), %ecx
mov cur_max(%ebp), %edx

mov $1, %eax
for_loop_begin:
    cmp %ebx, %eax
    jl loop_begin
    jmp for_loop_end

        loop_begin:
            if_loop:
                leal (%ecx,%eax,word_size), %esi #nums[i] = esi
                cmp %edx,%esi
                jg in_if_loop
                in_if_loop_end:
                inc %eax
                jmp for_loop_begin
    for_loop_end:
        mov %edx,%eax

        ret

in_if_loop:
    mov %esi,%edx
    movl %ebp, %esp
    pop %ebp
    jmp in_if_loop_end
```

This is the C code

```
short max(short* nums, int len){
  int index;
  short cur_max = nums[0];
  for( index = 1; index < len; index++)
    if( nums[index] > cur_max)
      cur_max = nums[index];
  return cur_max;
```

}

Comment: This is assembly.  So either you already answered your own question, or you are asking us to check whether this assembly code matches the C code, which is missing.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry about that forgot to put the C code. My Question is if my assembly code produces the same results as the C code if called from C

Comment: Why not just run it and find out? Or a lot of debuggers offer assembly level views of compiled code.

Comment: I did but i can't find the problem and I'm not that skilled in assembly.

Comment: What problem? If you want help on the problem then tell us what the problem is.

Comment: I'm having trouble converting arrays from c into assembly. Like for curr_max =nums[0] I don't know if the assembly i wrote for it is correct

Comment: Then make that the focus of your question.

Comment: How do I access nums[0] the first element in array in assembly?

Comment: @user3274039: it would be better if you edit or rewrite from scratch your question.

Comment: Your assembly code is *way* too complicated for what you're supposed to be doing. It's also completely wrong as a consequence. I'd advise you to look at the assembly a compiler would generate for your C-function.